# Regex Match Between Slug And Url

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, slug

Hi I want to check my routes if matched or not. Here is simple url path;

```
/blog/:slug1/:slug2
```

And here is my route;

```
/blog/foo/bar
```

How can I match them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the RegExp object in JavaScript to match the route and the URL path using a regular expression:

Voici an example :

```js
const route = '/blog/foo/bar';
const urlPath = '/blog/:slug1/:slug2';

const pattern = /^\/blog\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)$/;

const match = urlPath.match(pattern);
if (match) {
    console.log('Route and URL path match!');
} else {
    console.log('Route and URL path do not match.');
}
```

Comment: Can I make it dynamic for when I want to add ``:slug3` it should be match dynamicly?